# Subquery getting the parent addedby field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to create a field called Owner in my table where You select the AddedBy field where parentID is equal to the PostID so far it only prints out the first field and the second is always null. Im doing a subquery on a query. Im trying to get the parent AddedBy field

```
SELECT Level, Sequence, PostID, AddedBy, Title, ParentID, Path_String,
   CASE WHEN ParentID IS NULL THEN
       AddedBy 
   ELSE
       (SELECT AddedBy FROM cte o WHERE o.PostID = ParentID)
   END AS Owner
FROM cte order by Sequence
```

Im trying to get a count of all posts that related to the PostID joinded by ParentID in a join but im getting an error so when i do a group by of all the Fields i still get the error:- error is below

```
SELECT s.Level, s.Sequence, s.PostID, s.AddedBy,  
s.Title, s.ParentID, s.Path_String, 
Owner = COALESCE(o.AddedBy, s.AddedBy), COUNT(r.ParentID)
FROM cte AS s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte AS o 
ON s.ParentID = o.PostID 
RIGHT join cte AS r
on s.PostID = r.ParentID
ORDER BY s.Sequence;
```

i get the following error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sproc_GetPostsByThread, Line 34
Column 'cte.Level' is invalid in the select list because it is not
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

PostID, ParentID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String:- PostID is IdentityColumn Path_String is in this format 1/, 1/1/, 1/1/2 and ParentID is an integer

```
    Level       Sequence                    PostID      AddedBy    Title     ParentID    Path_String  Owner    Count
```

---

```
1     00000003                          3           kirkdm     test      NULL        3/           kirkdm   1
2     0000000300000005                  5           MikeDM     re: test  3           3/5/         kirkdm   2
3     000000030000000500000008          8           Joelene    re: test  5           3/5/8/       MikeDM   2
3     000000030000000500000009          9           kirkdm     re: test  5           3/5/9/       MikeDM   1
4     00000003000000050000000900000010  10          Crushanin  re: test  9           3/5/9/10/    kirkdm   1
```

Should be this

```
Level       Sequence                                     PostID      AddedBy      Title     ParentID    Path_String     Owner     Count column here
```

---

```
1           00000003                                     3           kirkdm       test      NULL        3/              kirkdm
2           0000000300000005                             5           MikeDM       re: test  3           3/5/            kirkdm
3           000000030000000500000008                     8           Joelene      re: test  5           3/5/8/          MikeDM
4           00000003000000050000000800000014             14          Christian    re: test  8           3/5/8/14/       Joelene
4           00000003000000050000000800000015             15          Zeke         re: test  8           3/5/8/15/       Joelene
3           000000030000000500000009                     9           kirkdm       re: test  5           3/5/9/          MikeDM
4           00000003000000050000000900000010             10          Crushanin    re: test  9           3/5/9/10/       kirkdm
5           0000000300000005000000090000001000000011     11          Tim          re: test  10          3/5/9/10/11/    Crushanin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.Level, s.Sequence, s.PostID, s.AddedBy, 
   s.Title, s.ParentID, s.Path_String,
   Owner = COALESCE(o.AddedBy, s.AddedBy)
FROM cte AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte AS o
ON s.ParentID = o.PostID
ORDER BY s.Sequence;
```

Comment: Perfect thankyou so much for that you're on to it. I've been learning quite a few new things about SQL in the last few days

Comment: Could you explain COALESCE to me please

Comment: `COALESCE` returns the first non-null expression. So the left join will show owner as the AddedBy value from the parent row, if it exists; if it doesn't, it will instead use the AddedBy value from the current row. See this Books Online topic for more details on `COALESCE`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Could you help me with a count of the sub query when i do a count i get an error: 'cte.Level' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I need to have them in Sequence order

Comment: Count of what sub query? Sorry you're going to need to show sample data and desired results. I don't know what you're trying to count.

Comment: In the sub query that you made or joined the children of o is what i want to get a count of it the replies.; This is a Posts table made up of sub posts children. Its a nested table with the fields of ParentID and Path_String

Comment: I still don't know how you define "children" - if we have PostID = 1, parentID of NULL, then PostID = 2, parentID = 1, then PostID = 3, parentID = 2, what is the count of "sub posts children"? Avoiding word problems is exactly why you should post table structure, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: Table as Follows: PostID, ParentID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String:- PostID is IdentityColumn Path_String is in this format 1/, 1/1/, 1/1/2 and ParentID is an integer ParentID is related to PostID have a look at my updated code

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following your updated code. LEFT JOIN then RIGHT JOIN? Again, please show some sample data (in the form of INSERT statements) and your desired results (in tabular form).

Comment: I did the best i could with sample data check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013933/get-a-count-of-children-join-clause