# Get a count of children join clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to get a count of all posts that related to the PostID joinded by ParentID in a join but im getting an error so when i do a group by of all the Fields i still get the error:- error is below

```
SELECT s.Level, s.Sequence, s.PostID, s.AddedBy,  
s.Title, s.ParentID, s.Path_String, 
Owner = COALESCE(o.AddedBy, s.AddedBy), COUNT(r.ParentID)
FROM cte AS s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte AS o 
ON s.ParentID = o.PostID 
RIGHT join cte AS r
on s.PostID = r.ParentID
ORDER BY s.Sequence;
```

PostID, ParentID, AddedBy, Title, Path_String:- PostID is IdentityColumn Path_String is in this format 1/, 1/1/, 1/1/2 and ParentID is an integer

this is my code for the first result:

```
SELECT s.Level, s.Sequence, s.PostID, s.AddedBy,  
s.Title, s.ParentID, s.Path_String, 
Owner = COALESCE(o.AddedBy, s.AddedBy), COUNT(r.ParentID)
FROM cte AS s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte AS o 
ON s.ParentID = o.PostID 
join cte AS r
on s.PostID = r.ParentID

GROUP BY s.Level, s.Sequence, s.PostID, s.AddedBy, s.Title, s.ParentID, s.Path_String, COALESCE  (o.AddedBy, s.AddedBy)
ORDER BY s.Sequence; 



    Level       Sequence                    PostID      AddedBy    Title     ParentID    Path_String  Owner    Count
```

---

```
1     00000003                          3           kirkdm     test      NULL        3/           kirkdm   1
2     0000000300000005                  5           MikeDM     re: test  3           3/5/         kirkdm   2
3     000000030000000500000008          8           Joelene    re: test  5           3/5/8/       MikeDM   2
3     000000030000000500000009          9           kirkdm     re: test  5           3/5/9/       MikeDM   1
4     00000003000000050000000900000010  10          Crushanin  re: test  9           3/5/9/10/    kirkdm   1
```

Should be this with a count of replies column
this is the code for my second result i want to get the second result with a count of sub-children:

```
SELECT s.Level, s.Sequence, s.PostID, s.AddedBy,  
s.Title, s.ParentID, s.Path_String, 
Owner = COALESCE(o.AddedBy, s.AddedBy)
FROM cte AS s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte AS o 
ON s.ParentID = o.PostID 
ORDER BY s.Sequence; 

Level       Sequence                                     PostID      AddedBy      Title     ParentID    Path_String     Owner     Count Children of Replies here
```

---

```
1           00000003                                     3           kirkdm       test      NULL        3/              kirkdm
2           0000000300000005                             5           MikeDM       re: test  3           3/5/            kirkdm
3           000000030000000500000008                     8           Joelene      re: test  5           3/5/8/          MikeDM
4           00000003000000050000000800000014             14          Christian    re: test  8           3/5/8/14/       Joelene
4           00000003000000050000000800000015             15          Zeke         re: test  8           3/5/8/15/       Joelene
3           000000030000000500000009                     9           kirkdm       re: test  5           3/5/9/          MikeDM
4           00000003000000050000000900000010             10          Crushanin    re: test  9           3/5/9/10/       kirkdm
5           0000000300000005000000090000001000000011     11          Tim          re: test  10          3/5/9/10/11/    Crushanin
```

Comment: As I suggested before, please post table structure (`CREATE TABLE`), desired results in tabular form, and enough sample data (in the form of `INSERT` statements) to prove the results are correct.

Comment: Where did 11, 14 and 15 come from? The first set has 5 rows, the second set has 8 rows. I don't know where the extra 3 rows came from, I don't know what "count of replies" means, and I still don't know which if either of these is your desired result. I'm not trying to be dense, but you really need to explain your question better. Perhaps someone else will have better luck.

Comment: The second is my desired result with a count column of the children that are related by the ParentID if you look at the Path_String Column scroll both of you'll see 3/5/ and then all the 3/8/ children well i want to be able to get a count for 3/5/ of its children so some of these will be null because some don't have a count because there will be no reply

Comment: Re-tagged question, this is neither about C# nor is it ASP.NET.

Comment: @KDM is `cte` a table or is it itself a 'cte' (which allows recursive functions)?

Comment: it is a cte or the result from a cte. so some of the nested children in the coulmn 'count' which i want will have null in it because there will be no children. If you look at the column addedby there is Jolene and underneith that is two replies so Jolene has count of 2

Comment: @KDM - I tried starting cleaning up the question but it is just going to take me to long. Skimming over it, I have to agree with Aaron. I can't make heads nor tails about it. To reïterate what Aaron asks, you should add *well formatted* in- and outputs where the outputs are correct for the given inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Add `group by` clause.

```
group by s.Level, s.Sequence, s.PostID, s.AddedBy, s.Title, s.ParentID, s.Path_String, COALESCE(o.AddedBy, s.AddedBy)
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to represent a hierarchy and show just the top level rows with a count of children. Grouping by everything is going to ensure that every single row shows up, and won't be much different than a simple `SELECT *`.

Comment: I get fewer rows in the group by clause have a look updated my code